Machine learning model with x and y arrays as input
I am trying to develop a machine learning model that can estimate the stress concentration factor Kt of V-notched specimens based on scans from the notch profile. The scans of the profile contain non-evenly spaced points (x and y arrays) and can vary in length/resolution. What type of model would be most suitable to interpret that kind of data?
I have looked into LSTM, but to my understanding that mostly requires evenly spaced data and just uses one sequence as input. Maybe CNN would work, but how should I format my data to keep the unevenly spaced points?

